# Google closure optimisation

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-closure-compiler

I pasted the following code in google closure for reducing the size,selected the option 'advanced'.

```
for(var i =0;i<7;++i)
{
   alert(6);
}
```

After compilation , i got

```
 for(var a=0;7>a;++a)alert(6);
```

So what is the advantage of changing variable name to 'a' and changing the condition to 7>a instead of a<7....Is there any performance improvement .If so why?

Comment: Changing a<7 to 7>a is to facilitate rollup of constants in expressions, as well as to hope for better gzip compression (since if you have both a>7 and 7<a, then they will be converted to the same text and thus compress better).  Changing the variable name to "a" is just a by-product of local variable renaming to one-character names (as much as possible) -- starting from a to z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advanced mode picks the shortest names possible. It starts with 'a'. The reordering is done to maximize gzip compression. Neither are helpful for a snippet like yours but these with other transformations can make a large difference to a more significant code base. Generally the compiler transformation are aimed at code size not performance but to be at least performance neutral.

Comment: "grip" do you mean gzip? And how would reordering improve that?

Comment: the more consistent the code size the better it gzip's.  So, if you have both "x==1" and "1==x", changing both to "x==1" results in better gzip compression. The compiler doesn't try to determine if it will help on a case by case basis it simply always does it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I can see that it will help compression that way.

Answer (score 3):

None.  I imagine you are just the victim of seeing useless transformations their engine does to put syntax trees into a canonical form before trying to optimize it.